# ASP.NET RC1 Error: IOException: Unexpected end of stream. in MultipartReaderStream

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I am getting an exception in the MultipartReaderStream that is only happening in the latest IE on Windows. Edge, Chrome, and Firefox do not cause the issue.

The code is using an embedded JavaScript for a survey that breaks forms in to multiple pages in a view through an ASP.NET 5 RC1 MVC app.

Additionally, this same script has no issues in an older ASP.NET WinForms application through Internet Explorer as well. And to make this even stranger, if I refresh the page with the exception the form continues without an exception.

The exception is:

```
IOException: Unexpected end of stream.
Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.<DrainAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.<ReadNextSectionAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.Internal.FormFeature.<ReadFormAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.<CreateValueProviderAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.<CreateAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeResourceFilterAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.<RouteAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Also, the headers will probably help with diagnosing this issue:

```
Accept text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e02b3d361384
Cookie ai_user=gzPsm|2016-02-09T17:38:51.618Z; ai_session=PDrtf|1455049518484|1455050340991
Host localhost:9481
Referer http://localhost:9481/assessment/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; LCJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
X-Forwarded-For [::1]:52143
X-Forwarded-Proto http
X-Original-Proto http
```

Thank you

Comment: Please upload a repro project to github and we can try to debug it.

Comment: Does this occur after accepting form input and posting a redirect? If your controller just returns e.g. HttpOK, does this error go away? I have one where I get this error, but ONLY after I Redirect() in the controller. I am using RC1.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, and as [Yablargo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416665/yablargo) had it ONLY happened after redirect (in IE only).
I was redirecting to a "GET" Action from a "POST" action
It only worked with me, after I made the action I'm redirecting to "POST" instead of "GET", and returned: 
return RedirectToActionPreserveMethod(action,controller,route parameters);